# STM32_2 Phase shift

Tags: stm32, pwm, delay, phase, phase-shift

I did PWM for 2 Phase. It works great, but after I stop my Timer Master and Slave in order to have Delay, I mean with `HAL_TIM_PWM_STOP`, doesn't work my timer slave any more.

Can you help me with that?

Here is my code, and my Tim3 works only one time and not permanently.

```c
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
HAL_TIM_OC_Start(&htim2,  TIM_CHANNEL_4);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_Delay(200);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
HAL_TIM_OC_Stop(&htim2,  TIM_CHANNEL_4);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_Delay(200);
```